# which distribution does support xen4?

Tags: xen, linux

i've just realized that ubuntu 10 LTS doesn't support xen anymore...

**So which distributions have native support for xen 4?**

With native support i mean, that i can simply install and update them with the systems packet manager (like apt on debian derivates)...

Thanks a lot for any reply :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debian 6.0 comes with Xen 4.0.1.

```
apt-get install xen-linux-system
```

should give you what you need.

Comment: and will it get supported for a longer time?

Comment: I would expect so. Debian is well known for longtime support of their releases.